# Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a problem when I install 'Archive_Zip 0.1.1' on the Linux server, but when I try to run the script to create the zip file it gives the fatal error

> Fatal error: Class `ZipArchive` not found in ...

where I put the code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
var_dump($zip);
$res = $zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    echo 'Error: Unable to create zip file';
    exit;
}
if (is_file($src)) {
    $zip->addFile($src);
} else {
    // echo "<br>" . dirname(__FILE__) . $src;//'/install1';
    if (!is_dir($src)) {
         $zip->close();
         @unlink($filename);
         echo 'Error: File not found';
         exit;
    }
    recurse_zip($src, $zip, $path_length);
}
$zip->close();
echo "<br>file name ".$filename;
```

but it doesn't find the class file.

Please tell me the solution. What should I do to resolve the problem?
I also put the `php.ini` file in the folder where the script is, but it does not work.

Comment: On Ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip`

Comment: @EricKorolev that give `E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip'` using ubuntu 14.04 with php 7.2

Comment: On Debian 10, it's simply `apt-get install php-zip`.

Comment: You can view this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60482998/4806585

Comment: For PHP 8 and 7.4 the extension is [no longer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) libzip. You compile PHP with `--with-zip` parameter now. And don't forget to restart Apache afterwards.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 use `sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip`

Answer (score 282, accepted):

For the [`ZipArchive` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) to be present, PHP needs to have the [zip extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) installed.

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) for installation instructions (both Linux and Windows).

On Debian and Ubuntu, you can usually install it with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-zip
```

Then restart your webserver. Example:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: I have installed Archive_Tar and File_Archive extensions on server

Comment: @parag then those aren't the right extensions, are they? The one in question here seems to be named "zip"

Comment: I search on google and put these extensions to server. This is the first time I'm using the ziparchive or creating the zip file, So I'm not sure that are they right extensions.

Comment: @parag see the page with installation instructions I linked to

Comment: @parag you will need to equip your server with the Zip extension. It's probably already installed on your local PC because you're using a development package like XAMPP or WAMP - those already come with the extension installed.

Comment: @parag if you have no root access to your server, you will have to ask the administrator to install the extension.

Comment: which extension is to be installed? can you please tell me the name of extension

Comment: @parag it depends on the machine. On Linux, I think this is the way to go: `In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip configure option.`

Comment: According to the PHP manual, ZIPARCHIVE is available from version 5.2.0 of PHP.

Comment: On ubuntu server using apt-get `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip `

Comment: Simple solution: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`. Then, edit the file `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` (In the "Dynamic Extensions" section, add the line `extension=zip.so`). This should solve it

Comment: For Docker `docker-php-ext-install zip`

Comment: As mentioned by @Luddig on ubuntu server after `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` you will need to restart the apache server `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: On Jessie linux `apt-get install -y libzip-dev` and `pecl install zip`, after which the extension `zip.so` has to be enabled in the `php.ini` file and apache restarted. However, when using docker, @DavidRiccitelli has the correct answer.

Answer (score 95):

On Amazon ec2 with Ubuntu + nginx + php7, I had the same issues, solved it using:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

Comment: after apt-get install php7.0-xsl  got the problem ... don't worry just apt-get install php7.0-zip  to solve

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip` for Ubuntu/php7.1

Comment: this does not work with `php 7.2` and always says `E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zip'`

Answer (score 46):

On ubuntu desktop, I had to do.

```bash
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

This installed the library but I still kept on getting the same error, so I had to restart apache using:

```bash
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and it worked.

Comment: The restarting apache did it, when combined with @pekka's solution

Answer (score 26):

I'm not seeing it here, so I'd like to add that on Debian/Ubuntu you may need to **enable** the extension after installing the relative package. So:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
sudo phpenmod zip
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Install `php7.0-zip` for PHP 7.

Comment: DON'T FORGET THE APACHE RESTART!!

Comment: Install php7.1-zip for PHP 7.1, php7.2-zip for PHP 7.2.

Comment: As far as I know there is no need to specify the PHP version. "sudo apt-get install php-zip" will select your system PHP version and was sufficient when installing for php7.3

Answer (score 25):

**First of all, The solution for remote server:**

If you are using **cpanel** you may have zip extension installed but not activate. You need to active it. For this case you need to go to **cpanel > inside software section > click on PHP version**. Then find **zip** and check it. Now save.

**You should see like the image.**
[image]

Refresh page. The error should disappear.

Note: If you dont found, contact server provider. They will install for you.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using a template builder and it would not export. I checked the zip checkbox, saved and voila. Thank you Kaylan

Comment: Have been trawling the net for hours for a solution, this was spot on for me! Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 11):

## Centos 6

Or any RHEL-based flavors

```
yum install php-pecl-zip

service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thank you. I have installed php-pecl-zip, but without restarting httpd. Finally found your answer!

Answer (score 9):

If you have WHM available it is easier.

Log in to **WHM**.

Go to **EasyApache** 4 (or whatever version u have) under **Software** tab.

Under Currently Installed Packages **click Customize**.

Go to **PHP Extensions**, in search type "**zip**" (*without quotes*),

you should see 3 modules

check all of them,

click blue button few times to finish the process.

This worked for me. 
Thankfully I've WHM available.

Comment: After choosing the 3 zip extensions,
Go to "Review" then click on "Provision" then click "Done" on the next page

Answer (score 7):

**For PHP 7.x**

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

**For PHP 5.x**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.x-zip
// (for example sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip)
```

**And then restart the Apache server**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

You also need to compile PHP with zip support. The manual says the following:

> In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip  configure option.

It's not enough to simply install the correct extensions on the server. Have a look at the installation instructions link Pekka posted earlier. My answer is just a clarification of his.

Comment: yes, but where should I run this commands on the server so that php runs with zip support

Comment: Is it a server that you control? If so I believe it's part of the make command when installing PHP. If it's not a server that you control then the only option for you is to try to have the sys admin do it. Sorry I can't be more precise-I've never installed PHP on a linux server from scratch.

Comment: I can confirm. Installing all those packages did not work. I had to ./configure PHP again with the `--enable-zip` option and make && make install again (PHP 7.4.8 debian).

Answer (score 5):

This worked

```bash
apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

and no need to restart `php7.0-fpm` manually.

> Unpacking `php7.0-zip` (`7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`) ...
> Processing triggers for `php7.0-fpm` (`7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`) ...
> `php7.0-fpm` stop/waiting
> `php7.0-fpm` start/running, process 1572
> `php7.0-fpm` stop/waiting
> `php7.0-fpm` start/running, process 1777
> Setting up `php7.0-zip` (`7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`) ...
> locale: Cannot set `LC_ALL` to default locale: No such file or directory

> Creating config file `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/zip.ini` with new version
> Processing triggers for `php7.0-fpm` (`7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`) ...
> `php7.0-fpm` stop/waiting
> `php7.0-fpm` start/running, process 2354
> `php7.0-fpm` stop/waiting
> `php7.0-fpm` start/running, process 2397

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with **CentOS** and **cPanel** installed server. I installed zipArchive package via cPanel and didn't worked as expected.
After trying with so many fixes suggested each and everywhere just the below worked for me.

First find the name for the correct package with the below command

```
yum search zip |grep -i php
```

Then use the below code.

```
yum install your_zip_package_name_with_php_version
```

In my case correct code to install zipArchive was

```
yum install php-pecl-zip.x86_64
```

I had the solution from this link.
[How can I inslatt zipArchive on PHP 7.2 with CentOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583881/how-can-i-inslatt-ziparchive-on-php-7-2-with-centos-7)

And this installation somehow enabled that package too and it also restarted the effecting services and after the completion of the execution of the above code zipArchive issue was gone.

Answer (score 4):

PHP 5.2.0 and later

Linux systems

In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip configure option.

Windows

Windows users need to enable php_zip.dll inside of php.ini in order to use these functions.

Answer (score 4):

**For Centos 7 and PHP 7.3 on Remi**

Search for the zip extension:

```sh
$ yum search php73 | grep zip
php73-php-pecl-zip.x86_64 : A ZIP archive management extension
```

The extension name is *php73-php-pecl-zip.x86_64*. To install it in server running single version of PHP, remove the prefix php73:

```sh
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php-pecl-zip #for server running single PHP7.3 version
$ #sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php73-php-pecl-zip # for server running multiple PHP versions
```

Restart PHP:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Check installed PHP extensions:

```sh
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
apcu
bcmath
bz2
...
zip
zlib
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue on GCP while deploying wordpress in the App Engine Standard environment. This solved it :

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 3):

For me work, first review

```bash
php -m
php -version
```

Later install the extension

```bash
apt-get update 
apt-get install php7.2-zip
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running into this error while using a Docker image and that you are calling the class properly, or that the error comes from an up-to-date library, then the `zip` module is probably missing.

Assuming we use `docker-compose`, we can confirm it's missing by running `docker-compose run php php -m` for instance and see that `zip` is not listed.

To install it in your image, modify your `Dockerfile` so it does the same as this example.

```
FROM php:7.3-apache 

RUN set -eux \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Then rebuild the image with `docker-compose build php` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 7.4 > The ZipArchive is not longer present by default and you need to install and configure it.

I strongly suggest using a library which you can just include in your project - like https://github.com/zanysoft/laravel-zip
This library is just a wrapper for the native ZipArchive

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS based server use

```
yum install php-pecl-zip.x86_64
```

Enable it by running: `echo "extension=zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the PHP version

If php version is 5.6 then, You need to install php5.7-zip

```bash
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

and then

```bash
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it had solved using two command lines:

`sudo apt install php-zip`

then reboot your web server, for Apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `\ZIPARCHIVE` instead of `ZIPARCHIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

## namespace

If you get this problem after adding **`namespace`** you can use the **`global`** namespace (backslash **\** ):

```php
$zip = new \ZipArchive;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CPanel [ Sharing Hosting ]
To fix this issue or error use the below steps:-

Error Details:-
/=========================================================================
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Filename: /home/b2bvniowy1go/public_html/system/libraries/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php

Line Number: 85

Backtrace:

File: /home/b2bvniowy1go/public_html/dashboard/controllers/Brand_price.php

============================================================================ /

cPanel Version [ 94.0 (build 19) ]
Solution:-  Do this changes to your remote server:  Cpanel > Select PHP version section > extensions tab. Then find zip and check it. Now save.
```

[image: zip setting in cpanel]

Comment: Worked on godaddy PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

The same in CMS Typo3 ver.11.5.8
while installing an extension by the Extension Manager,
nevermind that the Zip extension was installed in the cpanel.

### The reason: in the .htaccess there was:

### AddType application/x-httpd-php74 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php

The fix: change the above by:

AddType application/x-httpd-alt-php74 .php .php7 .phtml

Now it's working in me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use this class
use ZipArchive;

Answer (score 0):

- Goto php.ini
- Search for zip
- Remove ';' from that line (uncomment it)

Answer (score 0):

**Under Windows**

As of PHP 8.2.0, php_zip.dll DLL must be enabled in php.ini. Previously, this extension was built-in.

source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to find the currently installed PHP versions:

```
# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf --current
```

Once you have identified that version of PHP, you can then install the missing "Zip" module. You can install them with the following command:

```
yum install ea-phpXX-php-zip*
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for `xampp` users only**

If you are getting `Class "ZipArchive" not found` error message in `Laravel` then make sure following 4 things:

1. `zip` extension is enabled in the `xampp`, check it by `phpinfo()` function.
2. You are running correct `php` version in `xampp`.
3. You have set correct same `php` version folder path in `path` in Environment Variable on your windows system.
4. In the command line, first make sure correct `php` version by `php -v` command. If `php` version is correct then run `php artisan serve` command in CLI/command line console.

I am sure, this will solve your problem immediately. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

update for newer versions of php, the extension file is ';extension=zip' and not the complete 'php_zip.dll' file name.
just remove the semicolon from the start and this should do the trick.

Answer (score -13):

1) You should `require` your file with `ZipArchive` file.

```
require 'path/to/file/ZipArchive.php';
```

2) Or use `__autoload` method of class.
In PHP 5 it is a greate method __autoload().

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1(); // creating an object without require.
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: how should I include or require ZipArchive file?