# Class 'ZipArchive' not found: install it as non-root?

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a simple script that ZIPs up a text file but ZIPArchive() is not available on my server. Here is an example of my code:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./PJR.v2.zip";
if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
if ($handle = opendir('WORKDIR')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        $zip->addFile($entry);
        }
    }
  closedir($handle);
}
$zip->close();
?>
```

When I run it from the command line, I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /users/albert/zip_POC.v2.php on line 2
```

This is the version info on my server:

```
php -v
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2008 11:22:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
```

Is there a way that I can install that class even though I am not the 'root' user??

**EDIT**:

PHP was not compiled on my server with ZIP support. The `configure command` section of PhpInfo() does not show the --enable-zip option. PECL is not installed either so I cannot workaround my problem with `pecl install zip` either.

Comment: Here is a solution from earlier [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install or rebuild with ZipArchive, then there's also the pure PHP [PCLZip library](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) that you could try instead.