# Error setting up WURFL The ZipArchive extension is not loaded. Load the extension or use the flat wurfl.xml file

Tags: php, mobile, wurfl

Have any of you encountered this error before while running the demo of WURFL? I am tyring to user WURFL to redirect our mobile site visitors to different content but this error is not letting me go ahead.

Here is the error Detail:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WURFL_WURFLException' with message 'The ZipArchive extension is not loaded. Load the extension or use the flat wurfl.xml file' in /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/Xml/Utils.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/Xml/Utils.php(36): WURFL_Xml_Utils::getZippedFile('/var/www/bpaude...') #1 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/Xml/AbstractIterator.php(47): WURFL_Xml_Utils::getXMLFile('/var/www/bpaude...') #2 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/DeviceRepositoryBuilder.php(83): WURFL_Xml_AbstractIterator->__construct('/var/www/bpaude...') #3 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/WURFLManagerFactory.php(150): WURFL_DeviceRepositoryBuilder->build('/var/www/bpaude...', NULL) #4 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/WURFLManagerFactory.php(134): WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory->deviceRepository(Object(WURFL_Storage_File), Object(WURFL_UserAgentHandlerChain)) #5 /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/WURFLManagerFactory.php(77): WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory->init() #6 /var/w in /var/www/bpaudel/wurfl-php-1.4.1/WURFL/Xml/Utils.php on line 49

In the error, it also says "use the flat wurfl.xml" file. How would we use wurfl.xml as an alternative?

Thanks,

Bishnu

Comment: Have you installed and enabled ZipArchive ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in will help to install zip extensions and than your WURFL will work.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay! I have not installed ZipArchive and I was unaware of this thing.