# DrupalGap "Install SDK" Error: Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /../../.. /sites/all/modules/drupalgap/drupalgap.module on line 461

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, php-ziparchive

I am new to DrupalGap and while configuring DrupalGap I encountered the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /../../.. /sites/all/modules/drupalgap/drupalgap.module on line 461

**Reproduce Error**

1. Navigate to Configuration/Web Services/DrupalGap
2. In the "Directory" section, clicked "Install SDK" button.

I have looked around and haven't found a clear solution to this issue. A user on another SO thread recommended installing the "Zip extension". I've tried that but am still getting the error.

**Reference Thread**

[Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

**Additional Notes**

- This "Install SDK" step worked fine on my local environment. I followed the same steps on my server
- I'm running a D7 install
- I'm using DrupalGap 7.x-1.15

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **install** and **enable** **PHP Zip extension** to use ZipArchive class

*For Ubuntu*

- PHP7 : `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`
- PHP5 : `sudo apt-get install php5-zip`

Once the archive is installed restart your apache server and DONE !

*For Ubuntu*

- `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`