# ZipArchive does not work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

I have laravel project and whant to add feature for ziping files. I am using php ZipArchive. When I'm trying to create ZIP file using just PHP, I have luck, but when I'm trying with Laravel, zip files does not been created.

So I have add: use ZipArchive;
And just doing:

```
    $file_path = storage_path("creatives/helloworld.zip");

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($file_path, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

But there is not error and no zip file. What can you advise me?

Comment: Try returning your zip archive maybe?

Comment: I think you're creating ZipArchive in file with some namespase. So in this case you have to use absolute path to class name:
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

Comment: There's no error or zip file is highly unlikely. It's going to be either one or the other. However some zip operations don't throw exceptions, they just return `false` or an error code so you might what to keep an eye out. For example `open` returns either `true` (on success) or an error code.

Comment: Thanks for your response @devk. It's returning object:{ ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0) ["numFiles"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(0) "" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: When I run this code, it returns "File was created", but it hadn't been created:  if($zip->open($file_path, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
            echo 'File was created';
        } else{
           echo 'Failed';  
        }

Comment: The code you've posted won't create a zip file ___on disk___, just an "in memory" zip resource; it requires a `save()` call to actually create the file that (preferably after adding some files to the zip)

Comment: @MarkBaker you were right. The reason is I should add file to zip folder or save it to create file. Thanks

Comment: I created a Composer package some time ago to aid in handling zip and base64 encoded files and email attachments. It's not my best work, but it did serve me well in an enterprise environment, so you're welcome to use it or dissect it for inspiration. It uses a Provider to apply a custom plugin to the Storage service. https://github.com/kmuenkel/file-mutations/tree/master/src/Plugins

Answer (score 1):

It is very late to reply but this may help someone. I too had this same issue but then I opted for using "[Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)" and execute the command to create zip. 
If you are only concerned with the zip creation. You can use the following code.

```
<?php 
$projectFolder = $destinationPath;
$zipFile = $nameOftheFile;

$process = new Process("zip -r $zipFile $projectFolder");
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    // throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    $response['msg'] = $process->getOutput();
}else{
    $response['msg'] = 'Build zipped';
}
return $response;
```

Don't forget to install zip extension. Use the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```