# Class 'ZipArchive' not found in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I get the following error in a program called "Collective Access", but I am not sure where to go to from here given that I haven't ever had an experience with this type of issue before:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/core/Parsers/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/core/Parsers/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(268): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('project/mapping...')
#1 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/core/Parsers/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('project/mapping...')
#2 /var/www/html/providence/app/models/ca_data_importers.php(768): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('project/mapping...')
#3 /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/ca/Utils/CLIUtils.php(1147): ca_data_importers::loadImporterFromFile('project/mapping...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/providence/support/bin/caUtils(166): CLIUtils::load_import_mapping(Object(Zend_Console_Getopt))
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/providence/app/lib/core/Parsers/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 94
```

PS - This is the code around line 94 of the file it is referring to:

```
$xl = false;
    // Load file
    $zip = new $zipClass;
    if ($zip->open($pFilename) === true) {
        // check if it is an OOXML archive
        $rels = simplexml_load_string($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "_rels/.rels"), 'SimpleXMLElement', PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions());
        if ($rels !== false) {
            foreach ($rels->Relationship as $rel) {
                switch ($rel["Type"]) {
                    case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument":
                        if (basename($rel["Target"]) == 'workbook.xml') {
                            $xl = true;
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
    }

    return $xl;
}
```

### Edit

I'm using 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 for php (or just version 7.0 on Ubuntu Server 16.04.4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class is provided by the [Zip PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.zip.php) that, according to [its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) needs to be enabled on the compilation of PHP (on Linux) or in `php.ini` (on Windows).

There is a great chance that the extension is not available on your system. Write `<?php phpinfo();` in a new file, open it in browser (through the webserver) and check if the Zip extension is compiled or enabled.

If your script is a command line tool then run the [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) file using the PHP CLI or simply run in the terminal:

```
$ php -m
```

to see the list of loaded extensions (modules) or

```
$ php -i
```

to see the complete information displayed by [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).