# Symfony 3: I can't install ckeditor

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, php-ziparchive

When I follow [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/ivoryckeditorbundle.html) to "Integrating IvoryCKEditorBundle to Create a WYSIWYG Editor" in my app, I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException] Attempted to load class "ZipArchive" from the global namespace.  Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

This happens at the step 4.
I really have no idea about what could triggers this error. Due to my OS configuration? PHP Version? Symfony config? Etc?

Comment: Possibly a composer autoload configuration issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Comment: Possibly missing a PHP `zip` extension. `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Comment: I Try to edit from @jmd_dk edit but it doesn't work. I'm sorry I'm noob on stackOverflow. For my part, php7.0-zip wasn't installed on my ubuntu, thank you very much, it's resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please note that you can also change the php version, for 5.6 use sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue today and tried the solution proposed in the comments by Malcom (thanks, Malcom - it worked!):

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`