# Laravel import excel data error Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5

AAm using `"maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"`  to import data from an excel fuile but it fails with an error

> "message": "Class 'ZipArchive' not found",

I have

```
 $data = Excel::load('storage/app/temporary'.'/'.$request->input('file'))->get();

   var_dump($data);
```

Then am getting an error

```
 "message": "Class 'ZipArchive' not found",
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have imported

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

I have tried adding

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

but now gets an error

```
PclZip has a deprecated constructor in /home/geowan/Desktop/apps/laravel/importapi/
```

vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/PCLZip/pclzip.lib.php on line 190

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `ZipArchive`, you would have to install the PHP zip extension.

You can find more info on how to install it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php).