# How can I install zipArchive on PHP 7.2 with CentOS 7?

Tags: php

I am trying to install ziparchive and domdocument on nginx web server that has the latest WordPress. In order to run Avada theme, I need these two on the local CentOS 7 test server. I am searching for an answer for the past 3 days. What shoud I do?

Here is a partial list of "yum list installed:"

```
php-common.x86_64                   7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-php72<BR>
php-fpm.x86_64                      7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-php72<BR>
php-json.x86_64                     7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-php72<BR>
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                  7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-php72<BR>
php-pdo.x86_64                      7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-php72<BR>
php72.x86_64                        1.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-cli.x86_64                7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-common.x86_64             7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-json.x86_64               7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-mbstring.x86_64           7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-pear.noarch               1:1.10.5-6.el7.remi            @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-process.x86_64            7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-php-xml.x86_64                7.2.3-2.el7.remi               @remi-safe<BR>
php72-runtime.x86_64                1.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe<BR>

unzip.x86_64                        6.0-16.el7                     @base<BR>
```

Answer (score 31):

> php-json.x86_64 7.2.3-2.el7.remi @remi-php72
>
> php72-php-json.x86_64 7.2.3-2.el7.remi @remi-safe

Looks like your installation is a mess, you have installed half of the **php-** packages (base packages) and half of the **php72-php-** (SCL packages)

Read the FAQ about [Difference between php-* and php##-php-* packages ?](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

> php-fpm.x86_64 7.2.3-2.el7.remi @remi-php72

As you are using FPM as base package from **remi-php72**, you need zip extension from the same repository (which is probably not enabled, chech with `yum repolist`)

Drop the unneeded packages

```
yum remove php72\*
```

As explained by the [wizard](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl), enable the repository permanently to ensure all extensions will be pulled from it

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum install php-pecl-zip
```

> echo "extension=zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.in

Never do this, each package provides its configuration file to enable the provided extension.

Comment: THIS WORKED! I think you meant "yum remove php72\-" Anyway, it unistalled all PHPs, and I reinstalled it, then my problems are gone. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 29):

try `yum search zip |grep -i php` and install with package name came back

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install: php72-php-pecl-zip.x86_64. But after I created zip.ini as you said, it still did not work.

Comment: You can write a quick phpinfo(); script and check if Zip is enabled

Comment: Zip is not enabled in phpinfo(). Also, zip.ini did not exist, so I created one with vi. Was it wrong?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!  Not only that, but it also worked really well for other things that were missing, like exif.  It just became "yum search zip |grep -i php" and so on and that was all that was needed,

Comment: Thank you. It's worked on my CENTOS VPS.

Answer (score 9):

You can try: `yum install php-pecl-zip.x86_64`

Try installing that and enabling it by running: `echo "extension=zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini`

Comment: * base: mirror.steadfast.net
 * epel: mirror.cs.princeton.edu
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
No package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do     WHAT AM I MISSING?

Comment: try yum search zip |grep -i php and install with package name came back.

Answer (score 9):

This method works for me:
First type: `yum search zip |grep -i php` then it will appear you all modules related to ZIP extensions with various of PHP version like so:

```
ea-php54-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php55-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php56-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php70-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php71-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php72-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
ea-php73-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .zip
```

select whatever version you working with by: `yum install ea-php72-php-zip.x86_64`
finally, restart the Apache through `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me!

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this issue via the following:

```
yum install yum-utils
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum install php72-php-pecl-zip
echo "extension=/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

The issue was due to using the remi repo which doesn't place the module in one of the default locations PHP expects. Setting the absolute path to zip.so in the extension variable under /etc/php.d/zip.ini fixes the issue.

You can find the location of zip.so on your system via the following if the above path doesn't work:

```
updatedb
locate zip.so
```

Comment: Or you could add the zip module into the PHP modules directory `sudo cp /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/`
`

Answer (score 1):

try `yum search zip |grep -i php` and install with package name came back

like - `sudo yum install ea-php73-php-zip.x86_64`