# Laravel excel Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have laravel project with ability to upload data to mysql from .csv file using laravel-excel plugin.

When I try to upload data to mysql from .csv file, I get error "Class 'ZipArchive' not found". Can't understand what 'zip' has to do with it, if I use .csv
I am using: VMware Debian server, PHP 7.1

Everything works fine on my PC, localhost.

Comment: your project could be  using `ZipArchive` class , check your entire codebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens when you have not installed the zip-extension.

you can install it like

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```

after installing make sure restart the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do this on cpanel?

Comment: Solution works on Php 8.0 on cPanel.  Just had to activate Zip module in "Php Selector" section.

Answer (score 1):

For MS Windows Users:

1. Go to Xampp Server config file pannel `php.ini`.
2. Change the line: `;extension=zip` to `extension=zip` (Just remove the `;`
   before `extension=zip`).
3. Save `php.ini`.
4. Restart Xampp Server.

Comment: and how did you know if he's using Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-excel uses Phpspreadsheet which has the php_zip extension as a requirement. If you're only using it for CSV parsing, are you sure you need the entire laravel-excel plugin?

The solution is to install php-zip on your debian server or use a different method of parsing your CSVs.