# i want to create zip file in cakephp.But my code is not working?

Tags: php, cakephp

new ZipArchive is not working in cakephp it showing

```
error :=Class 
'App\Controller\ZipArchive' not found
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$fl_name = array('1.pdf', '2.pdf');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($fl_name as $file){
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: That doesn't read like an actual error message would. Post the actual error message.

Comment: Error in my cakephp is :   Class 'App\Controller\ZipArchive' not found       {
        $this->autoRender=false;
        $fl_name=array('1.pdf','2.pdf');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive; **//Showing error here**
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($fl_name as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Comment: This is a basic namespace issue, do some reading on that topic. You need to either add a `use` statement at the top of the file, or specify the full namespaced path to the class when you use `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example based on your names
Make sure the directory is read/write!!!

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./file.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/1.pdf","/1.pdf");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/2.pdf","/2.pdf");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();

?>
```

---

## update to "Load Vendor Files"

I recommend using composer to add ZipArchive source to your code. Adding ZipArchive via composer should "*just work*" for autoloading

If autoload is not working for any vendor (composer installed) code then take a look at [Loading Vendor Files](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)

Comment: Thank you for your code..Actually i am trying this in cakephp it is showing Class 'App\Controller\ZipArchive' not found  error.But this code is able to run in normal PHP file execution.Thank you