# Class 'ZipArchive' not found after php install and apache server restart

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error "Class 'ZipArchive' not found" even after php-zip install and apache restart. I'm currently running the project on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: what is the output of the following comamnds? `php -v` `php -m` `dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872555/fatal-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Comment: @RakeshMehta 'm running on php 7.4. When i run php -m, i can see that zip is installed. When i run the 3rd command, i can see php7.4-zip

Comment: What does your phpinfo() say? Don't see ziparchive there?  Try removing and purging php7.4-zip and install again using apt

Comment: @RakeshMehta From php -i, i can see Zip=> enabled Zip version => 1.15.6. I installed the current version with apt through apt-get install php7.4

Comment: @RakeshMehta i have realized that when i run php(info) in the browser, i cannot see the Zip module enabled. However, when i type in php -i, i can see that it's enabled. Could my Laravel application be using a different php version and the terminal references a different version?

Comment: No, that is definitely not laravel. When you run php from cli the environment differs compared to when you run it as cgi or fast-cgi. It seems like apache is not loading the required library. From which repo did you install php7.4, was it from ondrej or official ubuntu repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are running php as an apache module using libapache2-mod-php7.4, try to switch over to fpm by installing php7.4-fpm and libapache2-mod-fcgid.

Apache won't load a module / library if there is a version incompatibility and probably this is happening with your installation.

It should solve your problem. This article will guide you through the installation of php-fpm

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-http-with-mpm-event-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04

Though it is for ubuntu 18, but same will work on ubuntu.

**Note** PHP-FPM will speed up your web application as well.

Comment: I understand, how frustrating such situations are.. Cheers !